# How to close my while loop using -1 input?

Tags: java, while-loop

So i need to make a program that user has to guess the number until he gets it right. And he needs to be able to close the loop with -1 variable but im not able to figure out how to do it with my current knowledge of java.

This is the loop that i need to close

```
    random = generator.nextInt(435) + 456;


    System.out.println("Enter digit between 456 and 890 "); 

    randomUser= scan.nextInt(); 

    while  (randomUser > 1 && randomUser < 456 || randomUser > 891  )
    {
        System.out.println("1Input must be between 456 and 890");

        randomUser= scan.nextInt(); 
    }   



    while (randomUser != random || randomUser!=-1  )
    {

        if (randomUser < random)
        {
            System.out.println("Your guess was lower than the random number please try again");
        }

        else
        {
            System.out.println("Your guess was higher than the random number please try again");
        }

        randomUser= scan.nextInt(); 
        while  (randomUser > 1 && randomUser < 456 || randomUser > 891  )

        {
            System.out.println(" 2Input must be between 456 and 890");
            randomUser= scan.nextInt(); 
        }   

    }
    if (randomUser == random)
    {
        System.out.println("CONGRATULATIONS Your answer is correct!!");
    }
    else 
    {
        System.out.println("you exited the program");`
```

Whenever i try what i have in there i get this answer:

```
System.out.println("Your guess was lower than the random number please try again");
```

And i know why im getting it because my answer is lower than random number, but i cant figure out what i need to do to make it stop when you enter -1.

Can anyone help ?

Comment: you need to `break` the loop

Comment: you also will want to change your first while loop you probably want:

    while(randomUser != -1 && randomUser < 456 || randomUser > 890)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (randomUser == -1)
return;
```

That should do it, or some variation of it. Put it at the start of the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

Change

`(randomUser != random || randomUser!=-1)`

to

`(randomUser != random && randomUser!=-1)`.

You were using an *logical OR* (`||`), which will always evaluate to true, since the first condition (`randomUser != random )` is still met. Logical ORs short circuit after the first condition that evaluates to true.

*Logical ANDs* (`&&`) in contrast only evaluate when all conditions are met, which includes 
`randomUser != -1`.

Comment: This is actually the correct answer.  Not changing the second while's condition makes it necessary to add another if, to test for *the same thing* (i.e. the user has given the stop condition).

Answer (score 0):

Change this condition:

```
   while (randomUser != random || randomUser!=-1  )
```

to use &&

```
   while (randomUser != random && randomUser!=-1  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
while (randomUser != random || randomUser!=-1  )
```

to

```
while (randomUser != random && randomUser!=-1  )
```

The reason: Even if randomUser == -1 the way you have defined random ensures that it will never be true that -1 == random. So that while loop will never exit with a logical OR. Instead you need the logical AND.

Answer (score 0):

Change

`(randomUser != random || randomUser!=-1)`

to

`(randomUser != random && randomUser!=-1)`

`while` is a statement continues run if the logic in `while(logic)` be `true`.

First, focus on your logic:

`(randomUser != random || randomUser!=-1)`

`true` || `true` == `true`

`true` || `false` == `true`

`false` || `true` == `true`

`false` || `false` == `false`

Have only one case it make your logic return false:

`(randomUser != random || randomUser!=-1)` == `(randomUser == random && randomUser==-1)`

so that your while statement never end.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, the reason your loop doesn't break when -1 is entered is a mistake with the `while` condition.

I would also suggest a bit of a cleanup of the code, like this:

```
random = generator.nextInt(435) + 456;

System.out.println("Enter digit between 456 and 890"); 

while (True) {
    randomUser = scan.nextInt();

    if (randomUser == random) {
        System.out.println("CONGRATULATIONS! Your answer is correct!!");
        break;
    } else if (randomUser == -1) {
        System.out.println("you exited the program");
        break;
    } else {
        if (randomUser < 456 || randomUser > 890) {
            System.out.println("Input must be between 456 and 890");
        } else if (randomUser < random) {
            System.out.println("Your guess was lower than the random number.  Please try again");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Your guess was higher than the random number.  Please try again");
        }
    }
}
```

This should print out the messages as you specify them in your question, as well as correctly stop the loop when getting the input `-1` from the user.  This also returns control flow to the end of the loop whenever any of the termination conditions are met.